# show days, hours, minutes a go from mysql timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am tring to make this work.
what i want it's to show how long a go instead of the timestamp.

Found this function, but it works with unix date. tried to convert it using strtotime($fecha) but i echo it and its null...

you think i have to change plans or i only need to convert date format to unix properly?

```
function hace($fecha){
        //obtener la hora en formato unix
        $ahora=time();
        $fecha_unix = strtotime($fecha);
        mostrar_notificacion($fecha_unix);
        //obtener la diferencia de segundos
        $segundos=$ahora-$fecha_unix;

        //dias es la division de n segs entre 86400 segundos que representa un dia;
        $dias=floor($segundos/86400);

        //mod_hora es el sobrante, en horas, de la division de días;
        $mod_hora=$segundos%86400;

        //hora es la division entre el sobrante de horas y 3600 segundos que representa una hora;
        $horas=floor($mod_hora/3600);

        //mod_minuto es el sobrante, en minutos, de la division de horas;
        $mod_minuto=$mod_hora%3600;

        //minuto es la division entre el sobrante y 60 segundos que representa un minuto;
        $minutos=floor($mod_minuto/60);

        if($horas<=0){
                return "hace ".$minutos." minutos";
        }elseif($dias<=0){
                return "hace ".$horas." horas ".$minutos." minutos";
        }else{
                return "hace ".$dias." dias ".$horas." horas y ".$minutos." minutos";
        }
                }
```

Comment: what format has $fecha? is it a UNIX timestamp number or a datetime string?

Comment: if `$fecha` is a string that contains a parse-able date then the function should be ok.

Comment: as i said it's a timestamp and it contains, for example: '2010-12-22 10:12:30'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
$diff = $ahora - $fecha_unix;
$sec = $diff % 60;
$min = floor($diff / 60) % 60;
$hours = floor($diff / 3600) % 24;
$days = floor($diff / 86400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [this PHP manual's comment](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.time.php#96375)?